# Changes in Python text editor are executed immediately

Tags: python, scripting

I have a simple script that moves the cube. It seems that any change I make in the script is executed immediately (the scene changes) even if the script is not saved yet!
I do not think this is intended behavior.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

print('running')
Cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
Cube.delta_location = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 0))
for i in range (0,500):
    Cube.delta_location += mathutils.Vector((.01, .01, .01))
```

E.g. if I change the 500 in the range to 100 the cube moves to the origin at once...

BTW, this is on Linux Mint.

Comment: Turn off live edit in the text menu https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html#text-menu

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!